# Relations Of An Relation Objects - Cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, models, database-replication

I have three models: `User Image Group`.

- User belongs to an image;
- Group belongs to a User (admin)
- Group Has and belongs to user;
- User has and belongs to group;
- User and group model are connected with `users_groups` table;

When I am viewing a group there is listing the members (Users, this works) I need to extract them images what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). It will allow you to control what data you pull.

First, add it to your AppModel. I also always set `$recursive = -1` so extra data is never pulled. Be careful with doing this with an existing app that relied on `$recursive` data.

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $recursive = -1;
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Then, during a find call, use the 'contain' query key. For example, on your GroupsController:

```
public function view($id = null) {
  $results = $this->Group->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Group.id' => $id
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'Image'
        )
    )
  ));
}
```

This will bring in the User information associated with the group, along with the Image information associated with the users.

Comment: Awesome! This will also speed up your app by removing superfluous calls and joining data you won't necessarily use in a view.